# mySQL not excuting after being defined and called in cffunction

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, cfml, cffunction

I've been working on this for a while and figured an extra set of eyes (i.e. you guys) might come in handy. I've defined a mySQL insert query to be executed in a cffunction that is later called and passed variables. The cf code functions fine but whenever I go to the database to see if the code has been passed I don't see any data being saved. I know the database itself is fine because all other mySQL queries work the way they were meant to. Maybe I'm calling the arguments in the function wrong? Here's the code in question:

```
<cffunction name='sendToDiffQry'>
    <cfargument name="loanid" type="any" required="yes"/>
    <cfargument name="oldValue" type="any" required="yes"/>
    <cfargument name="newValue" type="any" required="yes" />
    <cfargument name="fieldName" type="string" required="yes" />

    <cftransaction>

            <cfquery name="diffInsert" datasource="STLinux1MySQL" result="diff">
             INSERT into tax_search_diff_table
                (
                tax_search_loan_id,
                 old_value,
                 new_value,
                 field_name,
                 timeofedit
                )
                VALUES
                (
                <cfqueryparam value="#trim(Val(loan_id))#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_bigint">,
            <cfqueryparam value="#trim(oldValue)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
             <cfqueryparam value="#trim(newValue)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
             <cfqueryparam value="#trim(fieldName)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
             Now()

                ) 
            </cfquery> 

        </cftransaction>
</cffunction>
```

And this is how I call it:

```
<cfset
        sendToDiffQry(url.tax_search_loan_id, form.old_frequency_id, form.frequency_id, 'frequency')>
```

I know I could call it within cfoutput tags too but I get the same results. I'm sure I'm missing something very basic here.

Comment: Your `<cfset` is fine. I would do a `<cfdump var="diffInsert"` to see what actually was inserted. Also you probably don't need a `<cftransaction`

Comment: I'll try that and see if I can find out if it's being passed along or not. the `<cftransaction>` is just there to make sure I don't save incomplete data

Comment: Revision to my above comment: `<cfdump var="#diffInsert#"`. On a similar note, I would also consider an SQL OUTPUT statement

Comment: I do not see any obvious errors that would prevent the data from being saved. As a troubleshooting step, return the query `result` from the function and dump it. What do you see? Probably not related to the issue, but a few suggestions 1) Always `var/local` scope function local variables - including the query "name" and "result" variables 2) You do not need `cftransaction` for a single statement. It is only useful when executing *multiple*, related, statements 3) It is a good practice scope the argument variables too, ie `#trim(arguments.fieldName)#`

Comment: If you run it with debugging turned on, do you see the sql being executed?  As an aside, the cftransaction tag is redundant if there is only one query inside it.  Also, storing a string in a field named timeofedit might be exceptionally unwise.  Finally, how exactly are you checking the database?  Maybe the insert is working and it's the check that's being done wrong.

Comment: @DanBracuk - Actually he is inserting a date/time value into `timeOfEdit`, not a string. But good point about "how are you verifying the insert?".

Comment: Well I figured it out actually. Some of the inputs I had going into the function weren't named correctly. So when it was going into the function the mysql was throwing it back and I didn't know. I found this out after commenting out each field that was going into the function one by one. I tried var dumping the query but cf kept throwing odd errors at me. I did var dump the results through later on. Anyway, it works now. Thanks for the help and advice everyone.

Comment: Oh and I forgot to mention. I am checking inputs in the .cfm file I'm working in. I check to see if the struct exists and then check for valid inputs of course. I'll go back and scope the variables as well.

Comment: *mysql was throwing it back and I didn't know* If the code is swallowing exceptions, you definitely want to fix that. *I tried var dumping the query but cf kept throwing odd errors* FYI: INSERT/UPDATE statements do not generate a `query` object, only a `result` object. Anyway.. glad you figured it out. Though it sounds like a localized issue. You may just want to delete this thread.

Comment: you should be scoping your variables too

Answer (score 0):

For tax_search_loan_id column you get the argument as loanid and use in the cfqueryparam  as loan_id, so try this code

```
<cffunction name='sendToDiffQry'>
  <cfargument name="loanid" type="any" required="yes"/>
  <cfargument name="oldValue" type="any" required="yes"/>
  <cfargument name="newValue" type="any" required="yes" />
  <cfargument name="fieldName" type="string" required="yes" />

    <cfquery name="diffInsert" datasource="STLinux1MySQL" result="diff">

       INSERT into tax_search_diff_table
       (
        tax_search_loan_id,
        old_value,
        new_value,
        field_name,
        timeofedit
       )
       VALUES
       (
        <cfqueryparam value="#trim(Val(arguments.loanid))#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_bigint">,
        <cfqueryparam value="#trim(arguments.oldValue)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
        <cfqueryparam value="#trim(arguments.newValue)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
        <cfqueryparam value="#trim(arguments.fieldName)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
        <cfqueryparam value="#Now()#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
       ) 

 </cfquery> 
</cffunction>
```